# Worklight support for Android 3.0?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Checking the supported operating systems with the IBM Software Product Compatibility Reports web page:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity/index.html

It jumps from Android 2.3 to Android 4.0.

Is it an error that Android 3.0 is not in the list?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 3.x is not supported by Worklight.

Comment: thank you. I have not seen many Android 3.x device, I always see 2.x or 4.x.

Comment: FYI - Google shares stats about what versions of Android people are using, go [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). Android 3.x account for only 0.1%.